# Populate Tablelayout programatically through String Array

Tags: java, android

Hello fellow stackoverflowers,

i just wrote this code to populate a tablelayout inside my activity_customer layout. For some reason in runs through without throwing the slightest error, but at the end of "populateView" the application just stops/crashes.

I tried some many things I found via google/stackoverflow, but none seems to work. I hope someone can help me find why the app stops.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer);
    populateView(DataClass.getReturnData());
}

private void populateView(String[] Array){
    int len = Array.length;

    TableLayout tab = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    if (len != 0){
        for (int i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);                
            TextView tvName = new TextView(this);
            tvName.setText("" + Array[i]);
            System.out.println(Array[i]);
            tab.addView(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Soulrox

Comment: provide the log details..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete example:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] row = { "ROW1", "ROW2", "Row3", "Row4", "Row 5", "Row 6",
                         "Row 7"
                       };
        String[] column = { "COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN3", "COLUMN4",
                            "COLUMN5", "COLUMN6"
                          };
        int rl=row.length;
        int cl=column.length;

        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        TableLayout tableLayout = createTableLayout(row, column,rl, cl);
        HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);

        hsv.addView(tableLayout);
        sv.addView(hsv);
        setContentView(sv);

    }

    private TableLayout createTableLayout(String [] rv, String [] cv,int rowCount, int columnCount)
    {
        // 1) Create a tableLayout and its params
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableLayoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tableLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        // 2) create tableRow params
        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        tableRowParams.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
        tableRowParams.weight = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            // 3) create tableRow
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            for (int j= 0; j < columnCount; j++)
            {
                // 4) create textView
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                //  textView.setText(String.valueOf(j));
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                String s1 = Integer.toString(i);
                String s2 = Integer.toString(j);
                String s3 = s1 + s2;
                int id = Integer.parseInt(s3);
                Log.d("TAG", "-___>"+id);
                if (i ==0 && j==0)
                {
                    textView.setText("0==0");
                }
                else if(i==0)
                {
                    Log.d("TAAG", "set Column Headers");
                    textView.setText(cv[j-1]);
                }
                else if( j==0)
                {
                    Log.d("TAAG", "Set Row Headers");
                    textView.setText(rv[i-1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    textView.setText(""+id);
                    // check id=23
                    if(id==23)
                    {
                        textView.setText("ID=23");

                    }
                }

                // 5) add textView to tableRow
                tableRow.addView(textView, tableRowParams);
            }

            // 6) add tableRow to tableLayout
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow, tableLayoutParams);
        }

        return tableLayout;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This description showed me everything I needed to get it working.